# aws s3 redirect rules and cache

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have redirect rules on my bucket with enable website hosting

```
<RoutingRules>
<RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
        <KeyPrefixEquals>avatar/</KeyPrefixEquals>
        <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
        <HostName>host</HostName>
        <ReplaceKeyWith>avatar/default-avatar.jpg</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
</RoutingRule>
```

when request host/avatar/user_id and this user doesn't have avatar it will redirect to host/avatar/default-avatar.jpg. when i upload new avatar for user and request host/avatar/user_id it will again redirect to default avatar. clear cache help. maybe someone can suggest workaround?

Comment: Have you find any way to do this? I'm struggling with the same thing for quite a time

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to Redirect tag:

```
HttpRedirectCode 302 /HttpRedirectCode
```

I omitted the `<>` because for some reason preview showed that text inside ignored :(

This will force the browser to evaluate URL every time instead of substituting it once. Hope this helped.